# Tableviewcell not displays image | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, decode

Admin can add image/text, the content displays, but the image doesn't do  it after adding. I need to add text to make image displayed. For example I can add a lots of images, they are in table, but they will not be viewed until admin add some text.

The thing is that I convert image in base64, add to array, and cellForRowAtIndexPath I decode it and add to a cell.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    var data = NSData()
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

    let base64String = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    let newImage = "imageBase64" + base64String

    content.append(newImage)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    if content[indexPath.row].rangeOfString("imageBase64") == nil  {

        let cell = self.articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Text Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextTableViewCell

        cell.textArticle.text = content[indexPath.row] as String

        return cell

    }
    else{

        let cell = self.articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Image Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

        let imageString = content[indexPath.row].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("imageBase64", withString: "")

        let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)

        let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.imageArticle.image = decodedImage

        return cell

    }
```

How do I make the image be displayed immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `self.tableView.reloadData()` in `func imagePickerController` after `content.append(newImage)` , maybe you forgot it